# Heroku Rails 3 all.css / all.js dynamic generation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm currently wrestling with a lot of all.js / all.css missing hits on a rails 2 upgraded to 3 app on Heroku. I'd prefer not to have a dozen or so stylesheet links per request, and also don't want to statically bundle -> s3 the files as part of the deploy.

This seems like a familiar problem, preparing some content specific to a url and sending it back to the browser.

Rather than using an external bundling app as part of a deploy script etc, has anyone considered having rails generate these files on-the-fly and use varnish to cache them (since it's cleared on redeploy, which is when the css/js files would change)?

My question is whether this has been done already & I just failed to google it, or if it sounds like a dumb idea, why?

Comment: You can't generate the files dynamically when hosted on Heroku because it has a read-only file system (apart from `/tmp`)

Comment: Yes, but we can render content, much the same as we do for HTML, and set the content type to js or css as appropriate. Page caching + cache busting would mean it happens only once per deploy. It's also possible to write to tmp and use rack middleware to host from that directory, but it's not possible to tell rails to use tmp instead of public for writing its assets, without nasty hacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even better: Rails 3.1 asset pipeline does exactly this, and Heroku handles precompilation and caching for you.